# How to keep in root a Wordpress installation and change the DNS for the only homepage pointing to an AWS S3 static HTML page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

On my EC2 instance Ubuntu 14.04 at the moment my domain `http://example.org` is pointing to my Wordpress MU installation, instead I wish to have `example.org.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` for the only homepage (is a static HTML page).

I tried this: `RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.org.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/` but the problem is that I cannot rewrite the URL with a normal rule on `.htacces` since this is a S3 static website.

A Wordpress MU must be in the root folder and cannot be moved to a sub-folder, so how could I keep my Wordpress MU and redirect only my homepage to S3 domain and change the URL in a nice one?

For the purpose, instead of edit the `.htaccess`, is it better to change the DNS?

Comment: There are multiple possible approaches, but the most appropriate solution will probably depend on why you are moving the home page to S3.  What is your reason for doing this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi, well I created a PHP script and for me it's much easier to keep it and serve it from S3, it's a landing page with lot of pictures so I think it's the perfect solution

Comment: That's a little confusing, too, because S3 does not support PHP.  S3 only serves static files.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry, it's my fault (I'm working on different projects at the same time)...it's an HTML page with a complex JavaScript

Comment: Option 1, put wordpress on a subdomain, and configure S3 redirects so that requests for `example.com/mypage` are automatically treated with a 301 redirect over to `subdomain.example.com/mypage` for any page not actually in S3 so existing links and bookmarks still work.  Option 2, proxy the request for the main page through your web server (which server software is it?) to S3, which will return the page, which you can return to the browser. Option 3, don't put the homepage on S3, put it on the web server with wordpress.  Option 1 would be my suggestion.  If that sounds usable, I have an answer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for reply, but if I remember correctly Wordpress should be in the main folder and not in subdomain (I'm on EC2 instance with LAMP setup and Ubuntu 14.04 as OS) otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, yes but no.  The "folder" (i.e. directory or path) and a "subdomain" are non-overlapping concepts.  You can easily put wordpress in the "main" (root) directory at "foo.example.com" (a subdomain of example.com).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is it possible for multi-site environment also? I don't think so...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So I think the only possible way is the option 2...could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this without changing DNS or the `.htaccess` file is to just use an `iframe tag` directly inside your WP Homepage pointing to your S3 bucket, like this:

```
<iframe src="http://example.org.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"></iframe>
```